# Use non standard types in Azure Easy Tables

Tags: sql, azure, xamarin

I'm trying to use Azures Easy Tables in my Xamarin Application.

I have data in 2 tables in azure which i added through csv. These tables include only standard types like string, date and numbers and are correctly synced to the device.

Additionally i have several other tables which are present in the local sync store. These tables / classes also use non standard types i defined myself. For example i habe a class Contact which has a property Company, which again is another class with several standard properties. These tables are currently only saved locally in the sync store, and it's working as expected. I'm now trying to sync these tables to to Azure Easy Tables.

So what i did was creating the table as an Azure Easy Table in Azure named Contact, with dynamic schema activated. When i try to Client.SyncContext.PushAsync() i get the following Exception:

```
MobileServiceLocalStoreException:
"Push operation has failed. See the PushResult for details."

Inner Exception / JsonReaderException:
"Failed to read errors from the local store."

Inner Exception / JsonException
"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: C. Path '', line 0, position 0."
```

Push Result seems to provide no information (Error Count 0)

I have no idea what this Exception tells me. Maybe the problem has something to do with the properties being non standard? How are these properties even mapped to an easy table. Is a non-standard property like company simply split into several columns like Name, Street, City?

Or does the Exception point to some other problem with the local sync Store? As i said, the local syncstore is currently working fine and the pull from azure easy tables for some tables is also working fine.

I'm grateful for every answer that might point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you solved this issue, do you need further assistance?

Comment: Unfortinatly i'm stuck with some other issues i need to fix, before i can get back to this. But i think your answer points me in the right direction. I'll try to change my data model the way you suggested, although i'd really like to keep using the Entity Framework way of just putting Company objects into Contact objects. If i understand your answer correctly i need to work with a company id and search/map the company manually in my code ? Thx for your assistance so far.

Comment: You are right. For offline sync, you need to manage the relationships in your mobile client, and when pushing local store to your backend, it would call the table endpoint for each of your tables and it would just update a single table for a http request. I recommend that you could refer to adrian hall's book for offline sync.

Answer (score 1):

Per my understanding, you are handling 1:1 relationships between **Contact** and **Company** tables. For offline sync, you need to define the Contact and Company classes in your mobile client as follows:

**For mobile client models**

```html
public class Contact : TableData
{
   public string ContactName {get;set;}
   public string Phone {get;set;}
   public string Address {get;set;}
   public string CompanyId {get;set;}
}

public class Company : TableData
{
   public string CompanyName {get;set;}
   public string Address {get;set;}
}
```

**Note:** As adrian hall's book [Chapter3 :Relationships](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/relationships/) states about relationships on mobile client as follows:

> There are a couple of rules you must follow within your client code:
>
> - You need to ensure that you create a `Company` before associating that Company with a `Contact`.
> - You need to store the `CompanyId` with the `Contact`, not the `Company` object (as you would normally do within Entity Framework).
>
> If you `InsertAsync` a `Company` in offline mode, it will be placed into the operations queue prior to anything that uses it. Since the operations queue is processed in order, the `Company` will be sent to the backend prior to any record updates that would use it.

For Azure Easy Tables, you need to create both Contact and Company tables, and it would automatically create the Node.js backend for your created tables.

I would prefer handling tables individually and handling relationship management on the mobile client manually which could make the server much simpler by avoiding most of the complexity of relationships. Additionally, you could refer to [Chapter 3 - Data Access and Offline Sync](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/relationships/).